# Getting the user's Facebook profile picture after Facebook authentication using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, reactjs

I am trying to implement a feature on my website where if you were to sign up or in with Facebook it would automatically put a profile picture. But I've been having some problems on implementing it. Here is my code:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krzDo.png]

I've done a lot of research including the Facebook Graph API documentation. But I never got anything relating to my question, I started to see if anyone asked this question already on this site but I didn't see anything. Well anything relating to uploading a Facebook profile picture in your app **with** React JS. Any help would be great. Thank You.

Comment: This question is really vague... You have two different problems. Uploading the picture (isomorphic-fetch on NPM?) or get the profile picture from the Facebook API? (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/)

Comment: The only question I have is how would I be able to make the user have an automatic profile picture when they log in with Facebook using ReactJS. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with upload and with React, just follow the link I've sent you, there you find the API to get the profile picture of URL of any user.

Comment: Which API should I be using because when I use the host url it gives me a nil image.

Comment: It is better to include your code in the question instead of a screenshot of your code.

Comment: "i never got anything" is not a sufficient error description. please add some debug information and more specifics what exactly did not work and what the outcome is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is this.

`this.getUserProfilePicture();`